# Sleeper in Selenium WebDriverWait constructor - what is it for (Java)?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I have checked Selenium documentation and I can see that there are three different WebDriverWait constructors including this (Java):

```
public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver,
                 java.time.Clock clock,
                 Sleeper sleeper,
                 long timeOutInSeconds,
                 long sleepTimeOut)
```

What is this sleeper for? I have checked and this his how it looks:

```
public interface Sleeper {
    Sleeper SYSTEM_SLEEPER = duration -> Thread.sleep(duration.toMillis());
    /**
    * Sleeps for the specified duration of time.
    *
    * @param duration How long to sleep.
    * @throws InterruptedException If the thread is interrupted while sleeping.
    */
    void sleep(Duration duration) throws InterruptedException;
}
```

I was digging for a while but still can't figure out what this parameter does. We already have timeOutInSeconds and sleepTimeOut to handle polling for a WebElement. Can someone help and tell me what is sleeper for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sleeper` is an interface that allows you to implement your own way how to make your code sleep. The default way is to call `Thread.sleep(duration)` however you might want your sleep method to perform some extra actions (probably prepare your code for sleeping or whatever). So that you can implement your own one which will make your sleeping different from default one.

**This is the default implementation:**

[image]

**This is what is happening when you do not use your own sleeper:**

[image]

Comment: Sooo you're saying this sleeper is used as a mechanism in each sleep method used then by WebDriverWait object?

Comment: Yup. Even if you do not pass some specific `Sleeper` to waiter there is default implementation that is used.

Comment: @Ela see my update